# Add Column To one table on inserting value to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `Branch_TB` and `Branch_City`.

Branch_TB :

```
CREATE TABLE Branch_TB(
Branch_Id int NULL,
Branch_Name varchar(50) NULL
)
```

Whenever there is an entry for `Branch_Name`, I want to add that entry as column `name` in `Branch_City`.

Is there any way for this. I don't know how to do this and haven't try any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either do it as part of the same stored proc/script which did the original insert, or use a trigger.

Comment: Just an aside,are you sure this is a good design?Or in other words how many values do you expect in Branch_name?

Comment: @Bridge can you please show it with example how to do this. please

Comment: @Mihai not more than 5 or 6. i want keep only one record for those columns in 'Branch_City'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER`.

```
CREATE TABLE Branch_TB(
Branch_Id int NULL,
Branch_Name varchar(50) NULL
)

go
--drop table BranchCity
create table BranchCity(abc varchar(20))

go

create TRIGGER dbo.AddCol
ON Branch_TB
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewVal VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @AlterSQL VARCHAR(100)

    CREATE TABLE #New
    (
    VAL VARCHAR(20)
    )

INSERT INTO #New
select Branch_Name from inserted

select @NewVal = Val from #New

SET @AlterSQL = 'ALTER TABLE BranchCity add ' + @NewVal + ' VARCHAR(20)'
exec(@AlterSQL)


END

go

insert into Branch_Tb
values(1, 'City1')

go

insert into Branch_Tb
values(2, 'City2')
```

But in my opinion, you should re-evaluate your database design.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create `trigger` on `insert` row in `Branch_TB` table.
In trigger you need to add code for Add `column` in require table.
[How to create Trigger in Sql ?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799.aspx)  check this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
create proc proc_branch (@b_name varchar(50)
as 
begin
exec('alter table Branch_city add column '+ @b_name + ';');
end
go
create trigger tr_branch
on branch_TB
for insert
as
begin
declare @branch_name varchar(50);
set @branch_name=(select branch_name from inserted)
exec proc proc_branch
end
```

Comment: can you explain This @Deepak, I don't understand this

Comment: menas how it will get adde as record and how it get added as column

Comment: i think @Deepak you dont understand my problem, am inserting Branch_name in Branch_TB and want to add that  Branch_name as column_name is Branch_City

Comment: @ChetanBodke I just edited the answer, trigger should be on branch_TB table

Comment: am trying your solution @Deepak but it gives error as : procedure or function 'proc_branch' expects parameter '@b_name' which was not supplied.. do you have any idea about this

Comment: i have edited your code @Deepak , But still there is an error as : Incorrect syntax near 'column'

Answer (score 0):

I understand it like you want to duplicate inserted value in some other table in column `name`. If this is true then you can try with `OUTPUT`:

```
INSERT  INTO Branch_TB( Branch_Id, Branch_Name )
OUTPUT  'someValue1', Inserted.Branch_Name, 'someValue2'
        INTO Branch_City ( someCol1, Name, comeCol2 )
VALUES  ( 1, 'some name' )
```

Comment: no no @GiorgiNakeuri I want to duplicate inserted value as column_name in another table

Comment: Can you show us code that inserts into BranchTB table?

Comment: Actaully @GiorgiNakeuri i have made this as demo to find solution for my problem.. real code is large , so for understanding i have made this